# TypeScript with React Native - why does useEffect require 'current' check?

Tags: typescript, react-native

I'm using React Native with TypeScript and I need to set the focus on an input if certain conditions are met:

```
  const inputEl = React.useRef<TextInput>(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (isLast && inputEl && inputEl.current) {
      inputEl.current.focus();
    }
  }, []);

 return (
   <View>
    <TextInput
      ref={inputEl}
    />
```

The code above works but I get a TypeScript error if I remove the `inputEl.current` check:

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (isLast && inputEl) {
      inputEl.current.focus();
    }
  }, []);
```

> TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.

Why is this happening? I'm checking for the existence of `inputEl`, so if it does exist wouldn't it always have a `current` property?

Also is my code correct or should the type be specified as:

```
const inputEl: React.RefObject<TextInput> = React.useRef(null);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`useRef` makes sure that `inputEl` always exists. However, it's current property is nullable. You specify that the `current` prop is initially `null` by passing `null` as an argument here `React.useRef(null);`. The `<TextInput>` component sets the `current` prop to it's own ref at some point, but since it's not determined when it's set, it could be null when the `useEffect` reads it. That's why you need to check `inputEl.current` and not `inputEl`.

You can also shorten you code like so: `inputEl.current?.focus()`. This is the equivalent of doing the check `inputEl.current && inputEl.current.focus()`.

Also, typescript can infer types and `useRef` is generic, so you can declare your ref like so:
`const inputEl = React.useRef<TextInput>(null)`

Comment: Yes it will be null until the component is first rendered after returning where a reference is actually set to the currently rendered component...